# ¿Es gramaticalmente correcto "Criaron a una nena desde bebé y ahora una jueza se *las* quitó"?

Tags: gramática, número-gramatical

Recientemente me encontré con un artículo periodístico intitulado.

> Denuncian que criaron a una nena desde bebé y ahora una jueza se **las** quitó.

¿No debería ser más bien "una jueza se **la** quitó"? El pronombre "**las**" no coincide en número y/o género ni con los que denuncian (un hombre y una mujer) ni con la nena.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La oración:

- Denuncian que criaron a una nena desde bebé y ahora una jueza se **las** quitó.

no es correcta. Debería ser:

- Denuncian que criaron a una nena desde bebé y ahora una jueza se **la** quitó.

Existe entre muchos hablantes, según [DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos) de América Latina, una tendencia a pluralizar el complemento directo (aunque el antecedente sea singular) cuando se usa "se". Como "se" (complemento indirecto) aplica tanto para singular como para singular, los hablantes sienten que pluralizan el complemento indirecto pluralizando -- incorrectamente -- el complemento directo:

> b) En el español de muchos países de América, es frecuente, especialmente en registros populares o coloquiales, trasladar a la forma singular del pronombre átono de acusativo en función de complemento directo el rasgo de plural correspondiente al complemento indirecto, cuando este va representado por la forma invariable *se*: «¡No entienden que este es mi espacio, es mi lugar! Cuántas veces quieren que **se los** diga» (Purroy Desertor [Ven. 1989]), en lugar de *Cuántas veces quieren que **se lo** diga*. Aunque en algunos países esta transferencia indebida se ha extendido incluso entre hablantes cultos, se recomienda evitarla en el habla esmerada.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!